# Is there a problem in recent jupyterlab versions which gives error: 'Segmentation fault: 11'?

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I have suddenly started getting a segmentation fault error when running jupyter commands which have always run successfully. I've tried `jupyter lab` and `jupyter --version` with the same result.
Using conda I updated jupyter lab recently on my computer which runs OSX 10.13.6. This maybe part of the problem. Here is conda history:

```
==> 2023-05-04 10:14:49 <==
# cmd: /Users/ivanscomp/miniconda3/bin/conda update jupyterlab
# conda version: 23.3.1
-conda-forge/noarch::attrs-22.2.0-pyh71513ae_0
-conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_server-1.23.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0
-conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab-3.0.16-pyhd8ed1ab_0
+conda-forge/noarch::attrs-23.1.0-pyh71513ae_0
+conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_events-0.6.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
+conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_server-2.5.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
+conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_server_terminals-0.4.4-pyhd8ed1ab_1
+conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab-3.5.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
+conda-forge/noarch::python-json-logger-2.0.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0
+conda-forge/noarch::rfc3339-validator-0.1.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
+conda-forge/noarch::rfc3986-validator-0.1.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0
+conda-forge/noarch::tomli-2.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
# update specs: ['jupyterlab']
```

I tried updating jupyterlab further to 3.5.0, with the same result on running commands. I tried creating a new conda environment with only jupyterlab and got the same error.

This seems to be a problem with the conda-forge jupyterlab, I created a new conda environment and used

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

rather than

```
conda install jupyterlab
```

which then ran as expected after

```
jupyter lab
```

Comment: Does everything in this environment also come from `conda-forge` channel? FYI, https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels

Comment: No, there are a minority of packages from pipy channel.